# How do you search for posts in slack

Tags: slack

Slack posts (rarely used feature I suspect)

I know I wrote a couple of such posts - how can I list all of my posts?  (or any specific user)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for posts in the `File browser`. Once in *File Browser*, you can filter type by `Posts`.

[image: File Browser search for posts]

Alternatively, in the search window, go the the files tab. Now you can use `type:posts` operator to filter by *posts*. Similarly if you want to filter by images, you can use `type:images`. This works on both desktop and mobile.

[image: Filter posts in search panel in Slack]

Comment: I can try this once on laptop but completly useless on Android.  But searching for a file "from:me" would be the easy part, how do I narrow it down to posts and not all files?  every image I ever posted, every email I ever forwarded to slack is shown as file

Comment: You need to filter _File type_ by _Posts_, you probably missed this part in the answer. If you are on mobile, click on `Files` in the search section and then filter using `type:posts`. I've updated my answer to add search window operation as well.

Comment: can you edit to have a TLDR at the top "from:me type:posts".  Probably new - I could have sworn I tried "type:post" before